# Spring Boot Maven Plugin moving files to the BOOT-INF folder in the Jar file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

Using Maven I am trying to include some license and copyright files in the top level of my spring boot jar. Those files MUST be at the top level to pass our company's review tooling.

I have included the files as follows

```
        <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/..</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
              <include>HERE_NOTICE</include>
              <include>LICENSE</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
```

Notice I have specified no targetPath (which should default to the root level). However when I create the jar (via mvn clean install) and look inside the jar the files are located in the "BOOT-INF" directory

```
     0 Fri Mar 15 14:40:20 EDT 2019 META-INF/
   615 Fri Mar 15 14:40:20 EDT 2019 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Fri Mar 15 14:40:20 EDT 2019 BOOT-INF/
     0 Fri Mar 15 14:40:20 EDT 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/
   519 Fri Mar 15 14:40:16 EDT 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/LICENSE
 12143 Fri Mar 15 14:40:16 EDT 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/HERE_NOTICE
```

My spring-boot-maven-plugin is configured as follows

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Is there something I can configure to keep those files at the top?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any option here cause spring boot works and has a special layout in it's resulting file for a particular purpose. I don't see any configuration options in the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html So I would suppose your company need to think about changing the review tooling.